# SQL query design not returning expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables in a SQL db named tbl_country and tbl_seaport

I am trying to create a query that returns all possible combinations of both tables using a join on field `CountryCode.`

```
tbl_country

Fields: CountryID, Country, CountryCode


tbl_seaport

Fields: PortID, PortName, RoutingCode, CountryCode
```

I started with the below but I can only get it to return 250 rows which is the actual table row count. I thought it would return 62500 (250 x 250) rows of data.

```
SELECT s.Country, m.Country 
FROM tbl_country AS s
LEFT JOIN tbl_country AS m
ON s.CountryID = m.CountryID
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: If you want to achieve all combination then you should not use join.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Get all country-country combinations including joining each country to itself, and then? How shall the ports be involved in the query? Also get all port-port combinations? Or only one port per country? Or what else?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I would like to create a query and make a table with that query which combines all country and seaport combinations but NOT including what you described "country to itself".

Comment: So ist combine all ports with all ports including each port with itself, actually, right? And then simply join the ports' countries. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @d1g1tr0n - I've just noticed, you're joining `tbl_country` to `tbl_country`, and yet earlier in the post you say that you want `all possible combinations of both tables`.  Is your mistake that one of the tables being joined should be `tbl_seaport`?  Then you'd get each country listed with each seaport in that country?  Perhaps giving simplified example table contents and desired results would help?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ MatBailie - You are correct. Firstly, I wanted to create one table with all possible combinations of countries using tbl_country and one table with all combinations of seaports using tbl_seaport.  In both examples, I would not want the same country or seaport to appear together (i.e. US-US in the country example or Seattle-Seattle in the seaport example.

Comment: From those outputs or tables, I wanted to then create a table that contains every port-port combination based on every single country and its seaports. It would look like US-Seattle - UK-Felixstowe and same the other way around but not US-Seattle - US-Seattle.  I hope this is clear I am new to this site and am just starting out.

Comment: It might be worth noting that I also have the CountryID stored inside my tbl_seaport as well if that could make it easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT s.Country, m.Country FROM tbl_country AS s cross JOIN tbl_country AS m
```

**EDIT:**
with regards to your comment, you can use below query to join 3rd table.make sure to remove any duplication column names.

```
with cte
as
(
    SELECT s.Country as sCountry , m.Country as mCountry FROM tbl_country AS s cross JOIN tbl_country AS m
)

select * from cte cross join tbl_seaport
```

*but, please reconsider your design*

Comment: That's better thanks. I wonder how sql can identify the join or does it automatically identify the primary key?

Comment: Any idea how I can add the second table into that as well?

Fields: PortID, PortName, RoutingCode, CountryCode.

Comment: Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The column 'Country' was specified multiple times for 'cte'.

Comment: That works now I just need to work out how to omit the same country-country combinations. For example, I have ANDORRA to ANDORRA etc...

Comment: @d1g1tr0n i don't think it really needs to identify a PK.  it simply takes all rows from table 1 and for each row assigns it a row from table 2.  it would just need to know the two tables you needed xJoin for

Comment: @d1g1tr0n : I hope the original question was answered. :)
with regards to duplicate columns, you may need to handle in where clause.

Comment: @Dark Knight - Legend. Thanks so much for the help. I will look into your suggestion elsewhere.

Comment: @d1g1tr0n : You are welcome! Mark it as answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already it is a CROSS JOIN that joins two tables unconditionally such as to build a cartesian product of the tables.

However, now that you clarified your request, it becomes clear that you do want a condition. Only the condition is not some column must match another as it is usually the case when joining tables, but the opposite: A record must *not* match itself.

Then it is actually all *seaport* combinations you seek. The seaports' countries are implicit, i.e. a seaport belongs to a country, so you can use a normal join to get it.

```
select 
  port1.portname as port1_name,
  country1.country as port1_country,
  port2.portname as port2_name,
  country2.country as port2_country  
from tbl_seaport port1
join tbl_seaport port2 on port2.portid <> port1.portid
join tbl_country country1 on country1.countryid = port1.countryid
join tbl_country country2 on country2.countryid = port2.countryid;
```

The above still gives you combinations twice, e.g. PORT_A-PORT_B and PORT_B-PORT_A. If you want to omit this, then Change the ON clause to `port2.portid > port1.portid`.

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner - thanks heaps for the additional solution to my question. Although Dark Knight already provided a solution that I used and modified to get my final result. I would like to add your solution as a possible answer to my problem as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

Please try following query

```
SELECT s.Country, m.Country FROM tbl_country AS s, tbl_country AS m
```

Comment: Suggesting pre-ansi-92 syntax.  `CROSS JOIN` has been the correct syntax for over 20 years.

Comment: As per my understanding cross join will do same thing.

Comment: Yes. But the syntax you chose to use has been deprecated, even by Oracle.  It should no longer be used.  As the correct and supported alternative has existed for over 20 years I have down voted your use of legacy, deprecated, un-supported syntax.